# Append to a remote file via FTP in shell script

Tags: shell, ftp, append

Is there any way to write/append to a remote file via FTP? I need to append certain content in the file located in the server? Is there any way to do with shell script?

Comment: You could download the server file, append to it locally and then push the file back to server

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL with the `--append` flag:

> (FTP/SFTP) When used in an upload, this makes curl append to the target file instead of overwriting it. If the remote file doesn't exist, it will be created. Note that this flag is ignored by some SFTP servers (including OpenSSH).

See [cURL man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html).